# Rename files based on the previous 2 directory names

Tags: powershell, renaming

I want to rename files based on the previous 2 directory names. For example, the file below:

```
C:\temp\288\Issue level 1\288 Temper inad.doc
```

I want it to be renamed

```
288-Issue level 1-288 Temper inad.doc
```

I have created the following powershell command :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\288\Issue level 1" -Filter *.doc -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name}
```

However it only renames the the file with Issue level 1, I want it to include the 288 folder at the beginning too.

Comment: Your selecting only files from folder `288\Issue level 1`, thus there is no reason why your script should rename also other files under folder `288`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `Parent` property of the `Directory` to get the previous directory name. Also I would use a *format string*:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\288\Issue level 1" -Filter *.doc -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}-{1}-{2}' -f  $_.Directory.Parent.BaseName, $_.Directory.BaseName, $_.Name }
```

Comment: Sorry, but how do I get parent X levels deep? is it possible?

Comment: You could write a function that builts you the string based on the passed directory level. Shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: well, I meant a somewhat "native" approach. you mean doing something with parsing actual string and counting number of ``\`` in it?